# ¿Por qué cerramos por duplicadas la preguntas relacionadas con NullPointerException?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, duplicados-exactos

Desde que uso es sitio he visto innumerables veces que las preguntas del tipo:

> NullPointerException...

Automáticamente son marcadas como duplicadas (refiriendo a [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados) como respuesta) sin hacer el más mínimo análisis de la pregunta para así determinar si el origen del problema es el mero hecho de estar usando un referencia a `null` (como una variable no inicializada).

Por ejemplo, ayer solicité la intervención de un moderador para analizaran la reapertura de este pregunta: [“Exception in thread ”main“ java.lang.NullPointerException”](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326541/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception?noredirect=1#comment592563_326541), por considerar que la pregunta referida para marcarla como duplicada no podría solucionar el problema del OP.

En el ejemplo anterior la solución viene dada por explicar que el método `System.console()` puede retornar null ya que la JVM no siempre tiene asignada una consola como por ejemplo cuando se ejecuta el programa desde un IDE. Este comportamiento puede generar un desconcierto muy justificado en programadores novatos puesto que esto no ocurre con la llamada `System.out` que siempre nos permite escribir en la salida estándar que casi siempre es la consola.

Como mismo [le respondí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326541/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception?noredirect=1#comment592744_326541) a un usuario que me decía que la pregunta estaba correctamente marcada como duplicada:

> "...Si la solución para, o explicación del porqué de, las NPE fuera tan simple como que estás intentando operar sobre una referencia a null la [JEP 358: Helpful NullPointerExceptions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358) no se hubiese creado..."

**Edición 09/02/2020**

Otros dos ejemplos.

[Uno sobre Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327966/me-da-un-nullpointer-un-imageview-que-tengo-bien-definido) (tal como dice @gbianchi) primero se ha marcado como duplicada y como el OP dice que la respuesta no resuelve su problema se ha reabierto y los usuarios han ido guiándolo para dar con su problema.

[Este sobre reflexión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326922/invoke-nullpointer-en-un-getter) que si ha sido marcada como duplicada y, aunque la respuesta tampoco resuelve el problema, como el usuario no lo ha indicado así se ha quedado.

Ambas preguntas tienen dos cosas en común: 1) Tratan sobre NPE y 2) El problema de fondo requiere una explicación más allá de: "Lo que ocurre es que estás usuando una referencia nula"

Answer (score 2):

Hay casos muy pero muy particulares (este es uno) donde la NPE no es un duplicado.

Pero en esos casos, OP deberia leer primero sobre NPE, y despues venir con el caso particular (como este) de porque en ese caso se da la NPE.

La pregunta (a mi parecer) como esta formulada (en el contexto por como esta escrita) esta bien resuelta como duplicada.

Lo que si se puede hacer, es editar la pregunta y transformarla en algo que diga, porque console me devuelve null. Entonces en ese caso ya no es una pregunta sobre NPE (aunque lo tenga implicito) si no que es sobre Java en particular y porque ese comportamiento.

Lo que pasa en esa pregunta lleva dos cosas, primero OP debe aprender sobre NPE y como descubrir que le pasa y donde le pasa, y despues de eso, entender porque Java se comporta de esa manera en estos casos.

Tranquilamente OP podria haber hecho una pregunta de seguimiento donde explicara que sabe lo que pasa, pero no entiende porque pasa (porque console no depende de el).

Comment: Eso está muy bien para programadores con cierta experiencia. Si vemos la pregunta el OP comenta que el código lo ha sacado de un libro tal cual y a él le lanza un NPE. Creo que pedir a los OP que aprendan sobre el comportamiento del lenguaje antes de hacer una pregunta excluye a los novatos. Por otro lado, ¿por qué mejor no pedirle a los usuarios del sitio que antes de marcar por inercia una pregunta relacionada con NPE como duplicada traten entender el contexto de esta?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que el título de la pregunta debería modificarse para que se ajuste más a lo que expone. Pero siempre va a ser mejor que los usuarios con experiencia guien a los nuevos para que aprendan a redactar buenas preguntas en vez de cerrarlas sin siquiera entenderlas.

Comment: @E.Betanzos en este caso, si ves el historial de la pregunta, quien la cerro fue el propio usuario. generar experiencia en un usuario novato tambien es ir marcandole los problemas 1 a 1.. si no, tambien se atascan en un problema medio sin entender el concepto. Y en este caso, igual que algunos otros, cerrar directamente por NPE no seria lo correcto

Comment: Que el propio OP aprobase el duplicado me indica que es un programador con poca experiencia que no entendió su problema, sino solamente qué es un NPE. Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo en que el modo de ayudar a los nuevos es indicares sus problemas, y este no fue el caso (como no lo es en muchos otros) ya que la pregunta fue marcada como duplicada a los 15 minutos de haberse formulado. Mi pregunta viene encaminada precisamente en lo que comentas de indicar primero los problemas, ya que como en este caso, la pregunta con otro título podría ser útil a la comunidad.

Comment: @E.Betanzos nada te impide hacer una pregunta al respecto con una autorespuesta!

Comment: Yo lo sé, pero lo que pretendo con esta pregunta es erradicar este comportamiento en el sitio. Cosa que por el contrario no ocurre en el sitio en inglés.

Comment: @E.Betanzos en ingles suelen ser mas estrictos de lo que es la comunidad aca. Sin embargo me parece muy bueno plantear este tipo de cosas. Para preguntas sobre android, no se dirige al usuario a la pregunta canonica, si no que se verifica el porque (para evitar estos casos)

Comment: Exacto! Si se hace con preguntas relacionadas con Android (lo de analizarlas) por qué no con todas. Yo se que muchas van a tener la misma respuesta, pero algunas otras no y eliminar esta conducta mecánica de cerrarlas sería positivo.

Answer (score 2):

Quizá estoy pecando de demasiado experimentado, pero mi sensación cada vez que veo una pregunta como la que enlazas es que el OP no ha investigado nada:

1. Tienes un NPE -> Algo que no esperabas que fuese `null`, es `null`.
2. ¿Qué línea falla?

   ```js
   nombre = System.console().readLine();
   ```
3. Vale, algo aquí es `null`... Probemos a hacer el código más explícito:

   ```js
   con = System.console();
   nombre = con.readLine();
   ```
4. Ya sabemos que el error es que `con` es `null`. Ahora podemos hacer una pregunta no duplicada e interesante: **¿Cuándo System.console() puede devolver null?**

Y por eso yo no dudo a la hora de cerrar por duplicadas esas preguntas: Me da la impresión de que el OP es muy inexperto y no sabe realmente qué es un NPE y cómo se soluciona.

Sobre el enlace que pones para hacer el mensaje de error más útil: Es verdad que podría ser mucho más útil, [como lo es en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/169194), diciendo qué el atributo o método se estaba intentando llamar cuando se encontró el `null`. Pero eso no impide saber que un NPE se soluciona viendo qué es `null` y, *tirando del hilo*, encontrar una forma de evitarlo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que este tipo de preguntas que se enfocan en el NPE indica que el OP es muy inexperto. Pero no crees que sería mejor analizar la pregunta y ayudarlo a darle la vuelta para que esta exponga el problema subyacente al NPE? Muchas veces, como es el caso concreto que expongo, el origen del NPE es muy interesante y puede ser útil para la comunidad exponer la solución. Mi problema no es con que se cierren pregunta relacionadas con NPE si realmente la respuesta es la de siempre, sino con el hecho de que son cerradas mecánicamente sin analizarlas.

Comment: El caso que muestro es un ejemplo claro de que aunque el OP no ha sabido enfocar su pregunta al problema real, este problema es interesante y su solución útil a la comunidad.

Comment: No se le ha votado negativo, la pregunta no es mala *per se*; sencillamente se le ha mandado a leer una respuesta que explica qué es un NPE. Una vez sepa esto puede hacer una nueva pregunta sobre la consola, si le interesa. O puede hacerla otro usuario interesado y autorresponderse

Comment: Eso es en este caso concreto, pero mi pregunta va dirigida a un comportamiento que he notado en la cominudad: marcar siempre como duplicadas las preguntas relacionadas con NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Considero que la pregunta esta correctamente marcada como duplicada. Diría incluso que es perfecta para su pregunta.

Es mas, como dice @gbianchi, si la pregunta estuviese estructurada o escrita de otra manera hubiese sido correcta.

Como comenta @Pablo-Lozano y se comenta en la respuesta canónica, si el OP depura su código encuentra el `null` y si encuentra el `null` encuentra su verdadero problema.

> Tienes un problema con el API. Has seguido todos los pasos arriba
>   comentados, y al final has encontrado que la causa del origen es que
>   estás llamando a java.util.Collections.toArray() y te devuelve un
>   valor null. Revisa la documentación del método, revisa los parámetros
>   que pasas, etc. Si sigues sin encontrar la solución,
>   **¡¡¡¡Felicidades!!!!** Ahora ya tienes una pregunta que es válida para SO
>   ("¿Por qué java.util.Collections.toArray() me devuelve null?")

---

No había visto este post en Meta, antes de verlo te había contestado en la propia pregunta:

> La respuesta de la pregunta marcada como duplicada es muy completa. No
>   solo explica que es lo que puede ser, si no por que este tipo de
>   preguntas no es valida para el sitio. `System.console()` puede retornar
>   `null` si se ejecuta en un `IDE`. [Java: How to get input from
>   System.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console) y [Java: System.console(), IDEs and testing](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html)

Como añadido a este comentario quiero decir, que creo que no es el primer caso en el que se marca como duplicada de esa pregunta canónica y se responde con algo similar a "Eso no me sirve".

Si se lee la respuesta **completa** se puede ver:

- Que puede causar el `NPE`
- Como encontrar el `NPE` (en muchos casos esto es lo mas difícil pero solo requiere depurar).
- **Que este tipo de preguntas no encajan en StackOverflow.**

Está última diría que es la mas importante, no te podemos ayudar a encontrar el NPE. Pedir algo así es similar a pedir que te haga los ejercicios que te han mandado en clase por que tu no los quieres hacer. Flaco favor le hacemos al OP ya sea de está pregunta u otra si le hacemos los deberes o le buscamos algo que debería de buscar el mismo.

Ahora bien y repito, has encontrado tu `null` pero no sabes como solucionarlo. Perfecto, ¡Pregunta!

---

Las fuentes enlazadas en mi comentario son el resultado de **1 búsqueda en google**, por: `System.console().readLine();` el segundo resultado.

Si ademas ponemos la palabra `null` sería el primer resultado.

Con esto no quiero criticar la falta de interés o las búsquedas del/a OP. Si no lo irónico de tu mensaje y cito:

> Automáticamente son marcadas como duplicadas (refiriendo a [¿Cuál es la
>   solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y
>   futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados) como respuesta) **sin hacer el más mínimo análisis de la
>   pregunta** para así determinar si el origen del problema es el mero
>   hecho de estar usando un referencia a null

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con casi todo lo que planteas, pero no debemos perder de vista el hecho de que la mayoría de los OP de este tipo de preguntas están iniciándose en la programación. Como dices, con una simple depuración puede darse cuenta de que el problema radica en que la llama a un método le está devolviendo `null`, pero en nuestros inicios no conocíamos o entendíamos como depurar el programa (por lo menos a mi me pasó). Yo considero que antes de marcar su pregunta como duplicada deberíamos convidarlo a que encuentre el problema real y que la reetructure...

Comment: El porqué la llamada a `System.console()` retorna `null` no se explica en el JavaDoc del método, lo que me hace pensar que dar una respuesta a esta problemática sería útil a la comunidad. Lo que quiero que se entienda es que me parece una mala práctica el marcar automáticamente una pregunta como duplicada al ver que se trata de un NPE. Este es solo un ejemplo, pero estoy seguro de que hay muchas más. No es ironía, si ves el timeline de la pregunta puedes notar que a los 15 minutos de haberse hecho ya estaba marcada; y esto es una práctica habitual de mucho usuarios.

Comment: Como dije, estoy de acuerdo a que el mejor modo de ayudar a los OPs es guiarlos para que aprendan a inverstigar sobre sus problemas. Pero en mi modo de ver las cosas, esto incluye analizar sus preguntas y si detectamos, como es el caso, que el problema de fondo es interesante y/o requiere de una explicación, indicárselo para que reformule su pregunta ajustándose al problema de fondo.

Comment: ¿En qué te basas para decir que "...este tipo de preguntas no es valida para el sitio..."?

Comment: @E.Betanzos Creo que ves las preguntas duplicadas de manera que no son. Según tus comentarios parece que crees que al marcar una pregunta duplicada le estamos diciendo al usuario "No te vamos a responder", cuando realmente lo que intentamos hacer es centralizar la información en una pregunta. Le estamos diciendo "Tu respuesta la tienes aquí". Respecto a tu último comentario es algo que ya he comentado en este post, no creo que buscarle el NPE a nadie le ayude en un futuro, todo lo contrario. Para eso se le enlaza a una pregunta en la que se le explica que tiene que hacer para encontrarlo...

Comment: Si lees mi pregunta verás que mi crítica va dirigida a que las preguntas relacionadas con NPE ni siquiera son analizadas antes de marcarlas como duplicadas. Estamos claros que la causa del NPE es el uso indebido de una referencia `null` pero es que muchas veces, como el caso del ejemplo que expongo, el problema subyacente es muy interesante y auqnue el OP no se haya percatado de este (muchas veces porque son programadores iniciándose en este mundo), es interesante y útil para la comunidad explicarlo.

Comment: La respuesta canónica que se le da a todas estas pregunta lo indica claramente: "...Si hay un NullPointerException, tu problema no es el NullPointerException...", y acto seguido sugiere una serie de pasos para determinar el problema real que los novatos muchas veces no son capaces de seguir. Esto es como dar una respuesta canónica a porqué una comparación de objetos con `==` falla. La respuesta la sabemos, pero hay muchas situaciones en que dicha comparación no fallará incluso cuando las variables tengas diferentes referencias a memoria.

Comment: Mi sugerencia es analizar la pregunta y si el problema es, por ejemplo, que estás usando un atributo de clase con referencia `null` porque no lo has inicializado pués está claro que es un duplicado. Pero en el caso de que el problema subyacente vaya más allá del uso de un `null` y sea interesante dar una respuesta, hacerlo. Una de las sugerencias de la referida respuesta genérica es revisar la documentación, y yo me pregunto: ¿cuántas respuestas damos en este sitio donde solamente hacemos referencia a la documentación? (ej. la doc dice X, por lo tanto esto que haces no es válido. Haz Y)